# Can I cure the Genophage without losing a Salarian?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've just finished the mission: "The Shroud" which involves distributing the Krogan Genophage cure.

Unfortunately, this mission ended with the loss of Salarian life

> -- one of my favorite Mass Effect characters, Mordin Solus.

Is there a way to complete this mission that doesn't involve the death of our Salarian friends?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Everyone's favorite patter-singing Salarian Scientist **can** be saved...

But the price, and required setup is arguably too high:

In order to keep Mordin alive, you need to have 1) Not saved Maelon's data in ME2, and 2) Urdnot Wreav must be the leader of the Krogans (that is, Wrex must have died on Virmire in ME1).

Incidentally, *this is the default state for a new, non-imported Shepard*. Under those circumstances, and *only* under those circumstances,

> Mordin can instead be persuaded to lie to the Krogans about the Genophage cure, and they will buy it, hook, line, and sinker. At this point, you gain both the Krogans and Mordin as War Assets.

Comment: I forget, is it possible to complete Mordin's loyalty quest without gaining Mordin's loyalty?  If so, this seems relatively easy for a Renegade Shep to do.

Comment: @MBraedley no, Mordin has no rivals in ME2 so you don't have a chance to make him lose the loyalty.

Comment: I love Mordin, but no way would I kill off Wrex to keep Mordin alive.

Comment: The question was about both curing genofage (not faking it) and saving Mordin. This is impossible.

Comment: Too bad that one of my favorite characters is Wrex.

Comment: @MBraedley Simply choose to destroy the data. You still get his loyalty.

Answer (score 3):

I saw [on a forum somewhere](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/9372705/16#9665953) that it is possible.

> You can convince Mordin to sabotage the cure, but Eve will die. You also lose the support of Wreav. However, either way you choose to go (sabotage or not), you can regain the support of the lost faction in another quest (so I'm told).

Comment: This is correct, and really, it's just another way of stating the conditions noted in my answer. Wreav won't be in charge if Wrex is alive, and if you completed Mordin's loyalty mission in ME2, Eve won't die.

Comment: +1 for only one to mention the support of the lost faction...

Answer (score 2):

You can complete Mordin's loyalty mission, but you need to destroy Maelon's data about curing the Genophage (this will get eve to die in me3). Wrex needs to die in ME1, but it has nothing to do with Mordin being loyal in ME2.

Answer (score -3):

One of my friends was able to use the paragon option to save mordin. I dont know how he did it. When I played it that option never came up.

Comment: That option comes up if and only if Wrex and Eve are dead, at which point it's possible to argue to him that with Wreav in charge curing the genophage will restart the Krogan Rebellions.

Answer (score -4):

Nope. This is the cost of curing the genophage.