# Can I resume a romance with Kelly Chambers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I realize she's never quite counted as a legit romance, but I ran into her in ME3 and

> convinced her to take the necessary steps to avoid the wrath of Cerberus

I'm told she'll show up again later.  Is it possible to rekindle things with her, and are there any special circumstances for doing so?  If so, will it affect any current relationships?

(I assume, like all characters introduced in Mass Effect 2, that if this is possible at all you have to have been involved with her in the first place, but since she didn't actually count for the Paramour achievement I can't be sure if this will be handled differently.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who can you romance in Mass Effect 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53601/who-can-you-romance-in-mass-effect-3)

Comment: @Sterno - She historically didn't count as a 'normal' romance option, so I figured it warranted asking on its own.  (Also, she's absent from the answer to that question.)

Comment: That just means the other answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Sterno - Well, it's also not the only question like this so I figured it was kosher.  If consensus agrees with you I'm happy to make any edits that might save it, of course.

Comment: The more I think about it, you're probably right, and I doubt you have to worry about anyone else VTC'ing it. The main question "Can I resume..." is a dupe, but the how, which Ben went into a lot of detail about, is definitely new and useful. Suggestion to make it clearer: Simply edit the title to say "How can I resume a romance with Kelly Chambers?" The main thing to avoid here is answers that basically just say "Yes, you can"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have a romance with her, and she's one of the hardest characters to romance. The [Wiki has the complete info](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kelly_Chambers#Mass_Effect_3):

> Shepard re-encounters Kelly on the Citadel...
> ...her death fate can be avoided if upon reuniting with Kelly, Shepard persuades her to "change her identity".
> She will disappear for a few missions. She will eventually reappear donning a new look and ask you how she looks.
> After the Cerberus raid on the Citadel, she can be found again in the Dock area of the Citadel...
> If Shepard didn't have dinner with Kelly during the events surrounding the Collectors, Kelly will be absent even if she survived those events.
> If Kelly was taking care of Shepard's fish during the Collector Attacks, she manages to take them when she left, and will return them to Shepard after the Commander runs across her on the Citadel.
> If Shepard is not involved in a romantic relationship with any other character, it is possible to pursue Kelly after she changes her identity and the Citadel is raided by Cerberus.

So if you satisfy those half dozen-ifs, half of them based on the last game, yes, you can romance Kelly. It sounds like you're most of the way there, though.

Note that unlike Mass Effect 2, romancing Kelly gets you the [Paramour](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_3) achievement this time.

Comment: Unfortunately it's awfully vague at the end.  More details than 'it's possible' would be great - do you have any firsthand experience with this?

Comment: Also - does she award Paramour in ME3?

Comment: Every romance awards Paramour except for the Reporter. Unfortunately I think she's absent from my save (no import). I think she sticks around if she survives the Cerberus bit, I'd just try talking to her a bunch...I romanced the Asari completely on accident by doing that.

Comment: @BenBrocka Can you update this to specify where exactly you run into her on the Citadel the first time? I had a fairly thorough ME3 playthrough yet somehow managed to avoid ever running into her, and the wiki link just says "on the Citadel". More detail would be helpful.

Comment: @Sterno unfortunately I don't know, my save doesn't have Kasumi to find. Does anyone know exactly where she is?

Answer (score 3):

She is available, and I have done it. Not only do you end up sleeping with Kelly in her container unit, but she expresses how happy she will be when she is together with Shepard after "this is all over". If you go back after that she gives you more dialogue, such as remembering how she danced for Shepard and too bad she doesn't have that outfit anymore. So evidently the save game remembered that, and it is a prereq for romance this time around.