# Where on the Citadel do I first run in to Kelly Chambers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Somehow I went through my otherwise-pretty-complete *Mass Effect 3* playthrough without managing to run in to Kelly Chambers. I did import a save from *Mass Effect 2* in which I'd saved her, so my understanding is that she should have been there for me to find.

I've seen [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55647/3062) about how to romance her, but both the answer and the wiki it links just says she's "on the Citadel". Since I apparently completely managed to miss running into her, I'm wondering:

**Where exactly on the Citadel is Kelly Chambers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She is in Docking Bay 2, in the first section of crates where the Batarians are (I believe, maybe 2nd row). She is in the back corner with her back to you. You have to go and talk to her before the first priority mission on the Citadel.

I can tell you why, but thats spoilers.

You can't get to Docking Bay 2, until you do the Priority mission to get Garrus into your group.

You have to have had dinner with her in ME2 to get her to show up, otherwise she doesn't. (thanks to FAE for the additional info).

Comment: Does she appear if she wasn't feeding your fish in ME2?

Comment: I think as long as you saved her in the final mission on ME2, she should be there. But I am not positive because I did the romance with her on my important, so she was feeding my fish. I think its just an extra perk if you spent more time with her in ME2 that you get all your old fish back.

Comment: You have to have had dinner with her in ME2 to get her to show up, otherwise she doesn't.

Comment: @FAE that seems to confirm my experience. I was fairly thorough in talking to all the people, but never saw her in ME3, and I didn't dine her in ME2.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ: did you definitely do the right stuff in ME2 as commented above?

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ: errr actually FAE made that comment as the third comment on this post which was the "right stuff" that I was referring to in comments. I've now submitted an edit to the question to include that info in there where it is more visible.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ: I went through pretty much the same thought process as you. And then remembered that even though I have low rep I could make an edit and have somebody else approve it. :) Hopefully next time people will find the info more easily.