# Where and when can I find Kasumi Goto in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assuming everyone survived in Mass Effect 2, where and how do they make an appearance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54211/assuming-everyone-survived-in-mass-effect-2-where-and-how-do-they-make-an-appea)

Where and when can I find Kasumi Goto in ME3? Also is she only in ME3 if you recruited her and paid for the ME2 DLC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kasumi is part of the Hanar diplomat mission on the Citadel. She needs to have survived in the 2nd game.

You also must complete the mission in 3 before the story mission involving the Citadel, or else the mission is lost.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's how to find everybody from ME1 and ME2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54257/21097)

I think you have to have recruited her in ME2 to see her in ME3.  Therefore, you would have needed to buy the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Kasumi is still around iN ME3 if she survived ME2 (meaning you got the DLC and she survived in your save). [ME Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kasumi#Mass_Effect_3) says she'll be on the Citadel, and she has some different dialog and scenes depending on whether you got her loyalty in ME2. She can be a war asset if and only if you won her loyalty.

Comment: But when and where....