# Location of all Citidal fetch quests in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am looking for a fetch quest list similar to "[Assuming everyone survived in Mass Effect 2, where and how do they make an appearance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54211/1770)"

---

What I have in mind is something like this:

Apien Crest: Banner of the First Regiment

- For: Turian officer in Purgatory
- Where: Castellus sector -> Apien Crest cluster -> Digeris

Comment: We already have several questions addressing individual missions. This question isn't very constructive to the Q&A format. If you have a question about an individual mission that's giving you trouble, that would be preferable to ask.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes, I don't see how this is different the character question

Comment: there's just waaaaay too many of them to list

Comment: @Elpezmuerto If you note my comment on that question, I didn't feel that one was a good fit for the site either. Please see [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3722/160) on Meta.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto I understand your frustration. You asked a specific question about Kasumi and it was closed a dupe, pointing to that all-encompassing character question. Now you ask an all-encompassing question, and it's closed for being too broad. You probably feel like you can't win. The main difference between the two questions, IMO, is that the character one didn't receive much attention until it already had a good answer, and was also asked closer to release when fewer people had a firm grip of how large the scope of the question was. It's unfair, but the answer basically saved that question

Comment: @Sterno, I've been a member long enough on SE that I am not frustrated. The Kasumi questions for AIP is a dupe. The problem we are having is that there are so many questions now and it has been difficult to find dupes based on how you word the question. But this is a problem for meta. No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really spend the time right now to write up all of them.

[The wiki lists all the missions.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Missions)

Just scroll to the ME3 Galaxy at War missions for the citadel.

Comment: The goal of this question is to not have my click through each link...