# How do I save Miranda?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Miranda died in my game, how do I save her?  Is it possible to do?  I don't have any saves older than the one for the mission, am I screwed?

Comment: You mean you saved during the mission she died in, not after she died, right?

Comment: I think that's what he meant otherwise I doubt he can do anything lol

Comment: yes, I have an auto save for the beginning of the mission

Comment: It's definitely possible, but I'm not sure under what conditions she doesn't survive, so it's hard to provide the counterpoint.

Comment: Just curious, are there any guidelines for spoilers in questions. >.<

Comment: @Extrakun 1) No. 2) This is Mass Effect, you should know its possible for nearly *anyone* to die.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have to have gone and met her at the Citadel earlier on, and warned her about Kai Leng (she sent an email way earlier on asking to meet).  The reason she is dead is because Kai Leng killed her, although it's not very obvious from the scene - the same thing happened to me and it is far too late to save her now.

Comment: I believe you also have to grant her the alliance resources. On the citadel she asks for support and refuses to tell you why. Your dialogue options are something along the lines of 'I trust you' or 'Not without telling me why'.  In my play through, Miranda was loyal from ME3, I met her by holo-channel and on the citadel after the attack, read the dossier on Kai-Leng, warned Miranda about him and took the renegade option with her father and still she died. Refusing to grant her resources was the only thing missing.

Answer (score 3):

To save Miranda, you MUST read the dossier on Kai Leng and meet her via a holochannel from the Specter terminal after the attack on the citadel.

During the mission, she may also die if you do not persuade her father to back down.  If that fails, you have to shoot him.  If Miranda shoots her father, then she be fatally shot in return and die.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation was really high, so I took the Renegade option. He let her go, and Miranda survived.

Comment: This is wrong, you are thinking of Oriana. I also have a super high renegade, took that option, he let Oriana go, Miranda blasts him through the window and he dies, then Miranda dies (presumably from exhaustion). Oriana lives.

Comment: no i am pretty sure she survived but she was also my romance from ME2

Answer (score 0):

You have to warn her about Kai Leng when you talk to her in Spectre Office.

Not sure does it play part in her surviving, but I also gave her access to Alliance database when she asked.

I did NOT slept with her in ME2.

Answer (score 0):

If you do warn her about Kai Leng and she isn't loyal to you in 2, then she dies. If you don't warn her she dies. I only want to save her if something romantically between her and Shepard and from the looks of it nothing does.

Answer (score 0):

If Miranda is your romance in Mass Effect 2 and you break up with her the first time you meet her in Mass Effect 3, then she will die no matter what actions you take in Mass Effect 3.

If you continue the romance, or did not romance her in Mass Effect 2, then you need to give her the Alliance resources she asks for in the apartment in Presidium. Continuing the romance does not mean it is locked in - you can lock in with another character later - it just means that you should not explicitly break up with her when you meet her the first time.

Answer (score -2):

Hmmm i dont know. I have played through twice so far and both times talked to her about Kai Leng and she did not survive either playthrough. My hypothesis is that she has to be a past romance or at least in an imported save from ME2. Both playthroughs I have done so far have been default non-imports.