# Can I change what happens to Thane?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In my playthrough:

> Thane was critically wounded by the Cerberus assassin on the Citadel. He died later in the Huerta Memorial Hospital.

[image]

Shepard and squad stood around being useless while Thane was fighting with the assassin. Is there any way I could have prevented this outcome?

Comment: Even if there IS a way to save Thane in this cutscene, why would you want to? He's been given mere months to live, so he was going to die anyway and frankly, to have such an awesome character die of some pissy illness is just insulting. He's a master Assassin, in the final stages of a terminal illness, and died going toe to toe with someone as badass as Kai while trying to help Shep. Very fitting ending for his kickass character, in my opinion :)

Comment: I had Thane as my paramour in ME2, and there's a whole long cutscene with him, his son, and (female) Shepard in an operating room after the battle of the Citadel. They have a long, stilted conversation, and he makes one last prayer for Shepard, so that she may forgive herself for what she's had to decide, and so she will be protected in the coming battle. Afterwards, Shepard receives a (very) long email where Thane really says goodbye, since he was in too much pain to say so earlier, and shares his last thoughts with her. It was very sad to read, since I was so attached to his character in ME2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only one way where [Thane](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Thane) survives the attack:

> If Captain Kirrahe survived Mass Effect's final mission, you'll meet him during the mission to recover the female Krogan.  If you didn't talk to Thane prior to the attack on the Citadel, Kirrahe will intervene instead of Thane and die in his place.

However, I wouldn't mourn Thane's death.  If you speak to Thane prior to the attack, you'll learn that he's near the end of his life regardless of what happens.  He says that one doctor gave him 3 months to live 9 months ago.  He also talks about his constant pain and feelings of suffocation.  For him, this is likely an honorable and worthy end.

Comment: Will Thane still be available at the hospital after that?

Comment: @kotekzot, I spoke to Thane, so he's dead in my version of events.  I learned there was a way to save him only after doing background research before answering this question.