# Thane Krios is in the dead list on Normandy

Tags: mass-effect-3

I can't find Thane, he isn't in Huerta Memorial Hospital and he is on the dead people list that is on the Normandy.  (The ones wich is in front of the elevator of the crew deck)

Is he really dead?

Answer (score 2):

If Thane is listed on the memorial in the Normandy, then he is dead.

If he survived the events of Mass Effect 2, in most cases,

> He is injured in the assault on the Citadel by Cerberus forces, and he dies shortly afterwards.

You may also be interested in this question:

[Can I change what happens to Thane?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54823/could-i-have-saved-thane/54840#54840)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he died, most likely shortly after the Cerberus attack on the Citadel, if he survived ME2. If he survived ME2 and you spoke to him in the hospital, he will help you repel the attack and get mortally wounded . You will have a short window of opportunity to visit him during his last moments, after which he will die.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he is dead. If you take too long to visit him in the hospital than you will miss some dialog.