# Are any important NPCs doomed to die, or immune from death?

Tags: mass-effect-series

**WARNING**:   Heavy usage of TVTropes links follows:

---

A compelling element in the Mass Effect series is that many significant NPCs have the potential to suffer [Permadeath](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FinalDeath) in battle, or at other key points in the game.  Many of these cases are made especially poignant for the player because the fallen NPCs could otherwise have re-appeared in the next game, and/or they died because of decisions made by the player.

In my first play-through of the series, I've had my share of player-influenced NPC deaths:

> - Ashley Williams
>  - Kasumi Goto
>  - Zaeed Massani
>  - Mordin Solus

While all of these characters are important contributors to the story in their own way, I was a bit grateful that they were not significant as some others.  One was obviously a non-optional loss (*someone* had to die in that spot).  The rest did not survive the first episode in which they appeared, and/or were relatively minor NPCs anyway.  Still, the game does fairly well to establish for the player that [Anyone Can Die](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnyoneCanDie).

However, I'm coming along far enough into Mass Effect 3 that I'm starting to consider my second whole-series play-through.  I'm thinking of having the second run be just a little bit more planned out than the first.  To that end, I'd be interested to know if there are any important NPCs (i.e.: those who are available as squad members in any Mass Effect game) whose deaths are beyond the player's control?

So, is there anyone who has immunity via [Plot Armor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor) or is doomed to [Death By Plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotlineDeath)?  Or are all major NPCs, by the end of the Trilogy, equally likely to have survived or been killed based on some player-controllable factors?

*(NOTE:  I haven't gotten to the end just yet, so I may still be missing out on some [Disney Deaths](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DisneyDeath), or the possibility that [Everyone Dies](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KillEmAll).  Annotate spoilers appropriately, please.)*

***In short: Which major characters' deaths or survival (if any) are not controllable or influenced by the player's decisions?***

Comment: Jenkins is doomed. There is nothing you can do in the first 30 seconds of gameplay to save him.

Comment: @kalina I'll hear no complaints from the duly warned.  Not my fault you lack willpower.  ;-P

Comment: waste of good ram

Comment: You let Kasumi die? _(storms off)_

Comment: He killed Mordin too. No one would ever kill Mordin, for no reason.

Comment: Hey, I didn't *kill* Mordin or *let* Kasumi die.  I just happened to make some apparently poor (and, in terms of meta-knowledge, uninformed) combat decisions.

Comment: To be clear - are you only interested in playable characters, or all characters?  You only mention playable characters, is why I ask.

Comment: @Shinrai Strictly speaking (as of the end of ME2) there's only two characters that are *playable* at any time in the series.  I'm generally looking for *major* characters.  Squad mates are the most common example.  Other major characters could be e.g.: Anderson or Udina.  Any characters that are mostly isolated to a single mission (plus or minus a follow-up e-mail and/or some other fringe benefits later) do not qualify.

Comment: Also, there's [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56691/1351), but it's specific to ME3 and squad mates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to your comment, you're only interested in recurring or important characters.  (I am not counting the post-gameplay ending of ME3 here, which has very obvious consequences based on choices you make in the ending sequences - you will know what you're getting into.)

To summarize without spoilers, when you ask "Are all major NPCs, by the end of the Trilogy, equally likely to have survived or been killed based on some player-controllable factors?" the answer is "Absolutely not".

In light of that, let's start with squad mates, since they tend to be more non-obvious and have more ways in which they can die...

In Mass Effect 1:

> You can shoot Wrex at the beginning of the Virmire mission, but this is entirely optional.
>
>  Either Ashley or Kaiden *must* be left behind to die on Virmire.
>
>  All other squadmates will live through the game - note that it's possible to skip recruiting a couple of them!

In Mass Effect 2:

> Every single permanent squad mate can potentially die during the Suicide Mission.  This is all of:  Tali, Garrus, Miranda, Jacob, Jack, Grunt, Thane, Mordin, Legion, Samara, (or Morinth, if you let her kill Samara during her loyalty mission), Zaeed, and Kasumi.
>
>  Shepard can also die during the suicide mission if fewer than two squad mates live (and if he does, you can't import that data to ME3).

In Mass Effect 3 (including previously-playable squad members who aren't playable in ME3):

> Any squadmate can be killed at the final mission if your readiness is too low and you take them in your squad.  EDI won't die (she's in the Normandy's computers), but her physical platform will be destroyed.
>
>  Tali will commit suicide if you don't properly handle the situation with the Geth.  Legion will die here in some manner or another no matter what you do.
>
>  Mordin can die on Tuchanka - if Wrex is alive at this point, it's impossible to both cure the genophage and have Mordin live.
>
>   If you sabotage the genophage cure, Wrex will figure it out and confront you, I believe he ends up dying at this point regardless of what you do.
>
>  No matter what else you do, Thane will *always* end up succumbing to his illness if he has made it that far.  This will happen off-camera if you don't visit him in time.
>
>  Jack will be turned by Cerberus if you don't help her on Grissom Academy, and you'll have to kill her.
>
>  Miranda will die if you don't warn her about Kai Leng.
>
>  Zaeed and Grunt can die when they show up if they weren't loyal in ME2.  Kasumi *maybe* dies, but it's hard to tell since it looks the same even if you end up finding that she lives.
>
>  Samara can die during her mission if you don't stop her from committing suicide.  Morinth won't show up there, but will end up turned into a Banshee by the end of the game.

As for non-squad mates:

Notable recurring NPCs who will die in the course of the series, at some point or another, no matter what you do:

> Anderson, Udina, Illusive Man, Kai Leng, Saren, Matriarch Benezia, Nyreen, the Clone

Notable recurring NPCs who may or may not die depending on your actions:

> Dr. Chakwas, Kelly Chambers, Engineers Donnelly and Daniels, Barla Von, Admiral Xen, Admiral Koris, Captain Kirrahe, Eve, Conrad, Balak, Shiala, Wreav (this one hinges solely on how long Wrex lives, you won't directly influence it), Maya Brooks
>
>  Also depending on your actions, the entire Geth race and the entire Quarian Migrant Fleet (although presumably a few Quarians elsewhere would have survived).

Notable recurring NPCs who won't die, regardless:

> Joker, Hackett, Aria, Aethyta, Bailey, Engineer Adams

Comment: Whoah!  Spoiler markdown, please!  Didn't read!

Comment: Apparently back-to-back spoiler tags are ignored.  Trying to fix this for readability, because that's a serious problem.  EDIT: And apparently this is deliberate, so I'm not sure how to format this well, it's a lot of info. http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/321/lists-in-spoiler-tag

Comment: To insert a blank line between consecutive spoiler paragraphs:  Put a double-space at the end of the first paragraph.  Put a spoiler tag `>!` followed by double-space on the blank line.  Then, start the new line with another spoiler tag.  You can see my edit in @DavidB's answer for an example.

Comment: That helps a little but it's still impossible to make properly formatted lists, so this is a bit uglier than I'd like.  Oh well.  (Also I'm *sure* I've missed a few names but all the other answers were REALLY incomplete).

Comment: Join me in chat?  I have some queries that I don't want to leave in open comments.  (Spoilers for some.)  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7113/mass-effect-series

Comment: Excellent post except that the second NPC you name as dying no matter what you do doesn't in fact die. In fact, I'm pretty sure they should be in the plot armour category because they narrate most of the ending cutscenes.

Comment: @Colmarr - Urp, you're absolutely right, not sure how that got in there and moving it now.  (Note that the ending cutscene narration varies wildly based on the ending you get, though - it's entirely possible to get an ending he's absent from).  Also added Citadel NPCs for the hell of it.

Comment: Wow, I had forgotten half of these deaths, and didn't realize a lot of these people could die (I guess I was very thorough).  Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned this up a bit to fit into the scope of 'not controllable or influenced by';

In Mass Effect 1, one of your initial squad mates (Richard L Jenkins) will die:

> As you walk around a corner within the first few moments of the first mission on Eden Prime, during a cutscene. This is to make room in your squad for Ashley Williams a few moments later.

The other uncontrollable death occurs later in the game - while you have control over *who* dies, you do not have the opportunity to save both of your squad mates...

> On Virmire, you have to choose between killing Ashley or killing Kaidan

In Mass Effect 2, the characters whose deaths you have no control over are:

> The entire crew of the Normandy SR-1, in my opinion none of these are 'major' characters although some of them did have a few lines to speak during the first game so I've included this to prevent an omission. The crew dies when a collector ship destroys the Normandy during the opening scenes of the game.

In addition, when doing Samara's loyalty mission:

> Either Samara or her daughter Morinth will die during this loyalty mission.

Finally, during Mass Effect 3, the following characters will definitely die and you have no real control over it. The first assuming that he survived in Mass Effect 2;

> Thane is very ill, and will die during the game in hospital on the Citadel.

During the missions on Rannoch;

> Legion will sacrifice himself and merge with the Geth.

And finally, although you don't have a choice on him dying, you do have a choice on how he dies;

> At the end of Mass Effect 3, the Illusive Man will die, either you'll kill him, or he will kill himself.

Comment: did not mention Ashley because he did it in the OP! The choice between the two is actually determined in ME1, when you have to send one of them to Virmire :)

Comment: Ack!  Could you put certain specific names, and allusions to potential end-game scenarios in spoiler-text please?

Comment: Depending on your choices and missions done in ME2, a former squad mate must die in ME3 when on the Krogan homeworld (left vague due to spoilers).

Answer (score 0):

In ME1:

> Jenkins dies on the first mission, unavoidably.  Wrex may die based on your dialog choices on Virmire.  Either Ashley or Kaiden will die based on your choices during the Virmire mission.

In ME2:

> Either Samara or Morinth will die during Samara's loyalty mission.

In ME2 final mission:

> Joker is the only person on the Normandy that is guaranteed to live.  Everyone else may live or die.
>
>  Crewmembers will die if the final mission is delayed.  Dr Chakwas dies if unescorted.  Un-loyal squadmates are at risk, in particular - Miranda vs Jack and Tali vs Legion.  Mordin is fragile, and there's a chance he will die even if you do everything right.  All of the "which squadmembers go where" decisions are life or death decisions.  If all squadmembers die, Joker is the only one on the Normandy so Shepard dies (game over).

(I don't have information about ME3)

Comment: Edited to spoilerize a name from ME2.

Answer (score -1):

**HEAVY SPOILERS AHEAD**

Beyond player's control, there is just few characters. This is strictly related to the story in ME3, so don't read if you did not beat the game yet.

> Anderson, Hackett and Udina, but they are not properly "squad mates". They fit in the category of "important and badass NPCs". Kai Leng also, on the enemy side.

The player still gets to choose which player dies (story choice for ME3) between this following list:

> Mordin, Tali, Legion, Wreav, EDI, Wrex, Kahlee Sanders can die because of storywise decisions

Some other characters deaths can be determined by your outcome of Mass Effect 2. If you saved them on ME2 and the imported that save, they will be in game as an added asset or just as a non playable npc encounter (just a talk, mostly)

> Morinth, Miranda, Samara, Zaheed, Kirrahe, Cortez, Eve, Grunt, Kasumy, Kelly

**PLOT ARMORED CHARACTERS**

All chars (hidden in second spoiler) are plot armored, since they can only die in precise moments of the story, and it's up to the player to decide their fate. Some of them can't die, though:

> Shepard, Liara, Joker, Barla Von (just remembered about him, lol.)

More about NPCs deaths [here](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/340145/features/mass-effect-3-guide-all-the-character-deaths-and-how-they-can-be-avoided/?page=1#top_banner)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Are all these ME3 spoilers, or are some from ME1/2?  Could you mark each according to which game is spoiled, if they're not all ME3?  (Haven't taken a peek yet myself, 'cause I don't know which parts apply to sections I haven't played yet.)

Comment: Also, could you address any characters (or the lack thereof) other than Shepard who have Plot Armor?

Comment: Last paragraph is spoilers from ME2, but it's the less spoiling one. The first one can reveal some plot twists, so i suggest you don't read it. The second one offers a list of characters that can die based on your story decisions. It's just a list of names, but won't spoil you when the choice is required or what the actual choice is, so you can read that safely (still it's upon you)

Comment: Updated :) The plot-armored section was needed in this list!

Comment: This answer appears to only address ME3.

Comment: Possibly spoiler-ish - in your last block you have Shepard listed as Plot Armoured. This is untrue, Shepard can die at the end of 2 and 3 (Shepard dying at the end of 2 results in a savegame that can't be imported into 3, for obvious reasons).

Comment: Well, if you consider that in the 3rd chapter you still get to play Shep (original shep, your shep, imported or not imported... it's still shep! he's even in the front cover of the game) that's not a great spoiler...