# Mass Effect 2 and 3 - Any way to stop Garrus Dying?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2, mass-effect-series

Firstly i just want to apologise if any of my information is incorrect. I took a long (Hopefully long enough) look at the Garrus Vakarian information on the Mass Effect Wikia page.

I notice in ME2 and 3, there's a risk of Garrus dying (Higher in ME3 apparently). I'd like to save him as i think he's quite an awesome squad member and character overall. I am partway through ME2, have just recruited Mordin after getting Garrus and done a few side-missions (Last one completed was the mechs destroying some crates..cant recall exact mission name). From what i can tell Garrus in ME2 will only die if i dont save him in time when on the bridge at Omega, if thats so then thats that sorted already. As for ME3 there seems to be a specific set of things that need to happen or Garrus, and alot of other normandy crew and squad will die at the end, of course i want to avoid this in my first playthrough so want to be prepared for it when i play ME3!

Any information is appreciated! :D

Comment: [Spoilerific answer over here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56704/1351) to a similar question (don't worry, it's mostly spoilerized).  Suffice it to say that Garrus is pretty hard to kill, even in the recruitment mission.

Comment: Generally in mass effect, if you take decent decisions and max out "crew loving" you should not have any problems keeping everyone alive. Just don't do stupid things like "hey, a bomb is about to explode under my ass, lets check crates for loot" and you should be fine. There are a few exceptions from this rule (like suicide mission), but you should be fine. Also... you have power over time called "save" :).

Comment: I managed to kill him only in ME3 final mission. Probably because of not enough reputation or I don't know why. The reaper killed him.