# Mass Effect 3 - Genophage Cure, Extra dialog options when saving Mordin?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When trying to convince Mordin to lie to the Krogran about the Genophage (so he doesn't die ), I find that the dialog choices to convince him are blanked out.  How do I unlock them?  Do I require a certain paragon/renegade rating?

Answer (score 6):

By blanked out, do you mean you see them on the left hand side of the wheel, but in grey?

If so, it means that **yes, your Paragon or Renegade score isn't high enough**.

Dialog on the top left/bottom left corner of the wheel occasionally shows up in Blue, Red, or Grey. Blue on the top Left is a Charm dialog, and often requires a minimum Paragon score. Red on the bottom left is Intimidate dialog, and generally has a minimum renegade score. Charm/Intimidate options for which you don't have sufficient reputation are shown in grey, because you cannot select them.

In the case of the Genophage cure, if you are in a position to convince Mordin to lie (which is [a complicated set of circumstances all it's own](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53843/can-i-cure-the-genophage-without-losing-a-salarian)), then either the Paragon or Renegade option will work.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Would Paragon be the requirement to save Mordin?  I would assume so, and yes, I do mean the greyed out options.

Comment: I believe in this particular case that either one will work.

Comment: its really weird for a paragon choice to work here since the result is clearly renegade oriented