# Is it possible to save both Mordin and Wrex in the second Tuchanka Mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I cure the Genophage without losing a Salarian?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53843/can-i-cure-the-genophage-without-losing-a-salarian)

During the second Tuchanka mission in Mass Effect 3, you can choose whether to cure the genophage, or sabotage it.

If you cure it, Mordin dies in an explosion. If you sabotage it, you are forced to kill Mordin to do so. However, you can save Mordin if both Wrex isn't alive and you destroyed Maleon's data in ME2. Additionally, if you don't cure the genophage and Wrex is alive, you are forced to kill him when he finds out that the cure was fake.

Is it possible to come out of this mission having both Mordin and Wrex alive? Please note that I saved Maleon's data in ME2.

Comment: The linked question definitively answers that it is impossible to save Mordin unless Wrex is dead.