# What caused Mordin to die?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I took all the paragon options, saved Maelon's data. Eve is still alive. I [know](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53843/can-i-cure-the-genophage-without-losing-a-salarian) how to save him.

BUT...

My favorite Salarian is dead.

What caused Dr. Mordin Solus's death? This was a little unclear to me in the story.

The cut scene shows a lot of lightning on top of the shroud. What caused that much lightning?

And finally what caused the explosion that took Mordin's life? Why was everything so unstable?

Comment: Hey, @desaiw.  I took out the mass effect series tag because this question is specific to ME3.  Also, we have lots of Mordin questions; shouldn't one of them answer this question?

Comment: Obviously, the shroud tower wasn't rated for Gilbert & Sullivan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on the following: *You've told Mordon about Dalatrass Linron's offer, he's aware of the sabotage, Eve is alive as you kept Maelon's data and Wrex is leading the Krogan.*

The lightning appears to be a secondary effect of the damage caused by the Reaper during your approach (where you're avoiding the reaper beam) to the Shroud Tower, and the Thresher Maw attacking the Reaper in very close proximity to the tower - see this video:

The lightning is not visible at long range both in the conversation before the approach and the conversation during the approach - if you look at around **6:50** there is a full upwards pan showing the tower with no lightning effect at all - yet if you look at **7:22** the tower has multiple minor explosions and lightning surrounding it.

As the long range shots also don't show explosions the only plausible conclusion is that the lightning is a secondary effect of severe damage to the shroud tower, which has also resulted in localised explosions.

The Shroud Tower is visibly falling to pieces as Shepard approaches. Mordin, in his personal desire to undo the actions of his past, personally wished to release the cure.

As he said himself; “Had to be me. Someone else might have gotten it wrong” - and due to the STG sabotage this could only be done from inside the tower's control room.

While he is releasing the cure, the Shroud Tower explodes and Mordin dies inside.

Comment: @desaivv if by 'lightning' you mean this here: http://youtu.be/Lp_gU_YAI20?t=30s - it wasn't lightning, it's a visual representation of the cure being released.

Comment: @desaivv and if by 'lightning' you mean this here: http://youtu.be/Lp_gU_YAI20?t=45s - it was the cure interacting with the atmosphere, there appears to be no 'thunder' sound effects and it's localised around the tower but without interacting with the tower directly, and only appears after Mordin announces that the genophage is cured

Comment: Yeah - that looks like it's going to be damage that occurred during the approach - if you see [this video (it's quite long)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSb7lxVn7Gk) the lightning is not visible at long range both in the conversation before the approach and the conversation during the approach (where you're avoiding the reaper beam) - if you look at around 6:50 there is a full upwards pan showing the tower with no lightning effect at all - yet if you look at 8:00 the tower has multiple minor explosions and lightning surrounding it.

Comment: Yeah it was a sad moment - "What caused Mordin to die" is he wanted to put the past right - he was aware of the consequences that unleashing the genophage on the Krogan had caused and he saw this as an opportunity for "a new beginning" - his last words before dieing. The explosions and lightning were caused by damage to the tower by the reapers, possibly secondary damage caused by the thresher maw when it took down the reaper, and the only way the cure could be circulated was by travelling up to the top of the tower, which had been sabotaged.